# Streaming HTTP Post Request

Tags: c#, sockets, http, tcp, httpclient

I was wondering if there's any solution to stream HTTP Post Requests from the server to the client on one socket connection that will stay up all the time.

Currently we have a solution to send HTTP Post Requests, but as we do it parallel (async), we are opening a connection per a request, the connection open/close takes several milliseconds which I want to save, so I was wondering if i'll be able, somehow, to keep the connection open and stream all requests through it.

Comment: Of course you can - this is what HTTP 1.1 was invented for.

Comment: Could elaborate please? maybe with some code samples and online references?

Obviously, we use HTTP 1.1 currently (C# WebClient / HTTPClient), but it still create new connection per request and not reusing the current connection.

Comment: I have no idea about C# WebClient. If it doesn't support reusing connections, you should abandon it.

Comment: "Requests from the server to the client" waitwat? If you want to stream post requests *from the client to the server*, you can take advantage of chunked encoding and message pipelining. Both are HTTP/1.1 features as @SergeyA correctly mentioned. But no idea if the C# Webclient supports any of these.